# How to ignore redirect and do not refresh the app on unauthorized route?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am building an ecommerce web app and if user is not logged in, but types private url, like `/profile` - I want to leave the page unchanged, but open a modal. The problem is: `history.goBack()`, as well as `window.history.back()` refreshes my whole app and resets my states. And my modal opens just for a split second before that refresh. What can I do to just ignore the redirect and do not refresh the app? Thank you.

**index.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <App />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**App.js:**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import Navigation from './components/Navigation/Navigation';
import Main from './components/Main/Main';
import { SuccessModal, ErrorModal } from './components/Modal/Modal';
import {
  ScrollTargetContext,
  CartContext,
  ModalContext,
  Tokens,
} from './contexts';

const App = () => {
  const [tokens, setTokens] = useState(null);
  const [successModalOpen, setSuccessModalOpen] = useState(false);
  const [successModalMessage, setSuccessModalMessage] = useState('');
  const closeSuccessModal = () => setSuccessModalOpen(false);
  const [errorModalOpen, setErrorModalOpen] = useState(false);
  const [errorModalMessage, setErrorModalMessage] = useState('');
  const closeErrorModal = () => setErrorModalOpen(false);
  return (
    <Tokens.Provider value={{ tokens, setTokens }}>
      <SuccessModal
        isOpen={successModalOpen}
        onClose={closeSuccessModal}
        message={successModalMessage}
      />
      <ErrorModal
        isOpen={errorModalOpen}
        onClose={closeErrorModal}
        message={errorModalMessage}
      />
      <ModalContext.Provider
        value={{
          setSuccessModalOpen,
          setSuccessModalMessage,
          setErrorModalOpen,
          setErrorModalMessage,
        }}
      >
        <Main />
      </ModalContext.Provider>
    </Tokens.Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Main.js:**

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

import { Tokens, ModalContext } from '../../contexts';

import Home from '../../pages/Home';
import Contacts from '../../pages/Contacts';
import About from '../../pages/About';
import Profile from '../../pages/Profile';

function PrivateRoute({ component, children, ...rest }) {
  const { tokens } = useContext(Tokens);
  const { setErrorModalOpen, setErrorModalMessage } = useContext(ModalContext);
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={({ history }) => {
        if (tokens) {
          return component || children;
        }
        history.goBack();
        setErrorModalMessage('You need to log in\nto view that page.');
        setErrorModalOpen(true);
        return null;
      }}
    />
  );
}

export default function Main() {
  return (
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Redirect to="/home" />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
        <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contacts} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/profile" component={Profile} />
      </Switch>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `history.goBack()` and instead of null return `<Redirect to="/" />`

**UPDATE**

```
export default function Main() {
  const { tokens } = useContext(Tokens);

  return (
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Redirect to="/home" />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
        <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contacts} />
        { token && (
             <Route exact path="/profile" component={Profile} />
        ) }        
      </Switch>
  );
}
```

Comment: If I understand right - that would redirect me home. But if I was in `products` I want to stay there.

Comment: So maybe you should create route only for users with token ? Check update in answer ..

Comment: Redirecting back when user is not login can be very frustrating for your users because they wouldn't know what just happen.. imo the best way is to redirect to login page with message "you are not logged in" or something like that.

Comment: Doing the way you updated the answer - would get me to 404 page (I did not include this route for code simplify).

About the seccond comment - I understood you, but I do open an error modal message in `PrivateRoute`, as you can see.

Comment: Another idea which I can image is to add previous location too all ```Link```, but it can be much work to do and it's always risk that you forgot to do it somewhere ```<Link to={{pathname: "/profile",state: { from: localtion.pathname }}}/>  then you can get back this path using ```location.state.from``` but I think it's kind a mess..

Comment: Yeah... If only I could get the previous location value. But location or document `referer`s did not work here.

Comment: Hmm.. maybe you can create custom component for all profile links like ```ProfileLink``` and then only import it where you need ?

Comment: Links are not the biggest problem. Cause there would be only one and even it would not exist if `tokens` are not there. But the manual url typing is a problem :)

Comment: Maybe that would help me :) https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-last-location

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess if you type in the page manually, then browser refreshes, so no previous pages. And the only way is to specify a auth error page redirect, or to redirect to `/`, for example, and call a error/login modal.